# Can we call va_end without invoking va_start?

Tags: c++, c

If my understanding is correct `va_end` is called for cleanup and in the same context, man page for `va_end` says that

> va_end()
>
> Each invocation of va_start() must be matched by a corresponding
>   invocation of va_end() in the same function. After the call va_end(ap)
>   the variable ap is undefined. Multiple traversals of the list, each
>   bracketed by va_start() and va_end() are possible. va_end() may be a
>   macro or a function.

So it's obvious `va_end` needs to be called if `va_start` is called, but does the reverse relation holds true i.e. should `va_end` be always preceded by `va_start`?

Comment: I added the [C] tag for you, since `va_end` is originally from C. There is only very limited use (at best) for variable argument lists in C++, since they are not typesafe, are not aware of classes (constructors etc) and have better alternatives like e.g. variadic templates.

Comment: Short answer, no. As Michael Burr said it's undefined behaviour. There are implementations that use malloc/free under the hood of va_start/va_end definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C99 7.15.1.3/2 "The `va_end` macro":

> If there is no corresponding invocation of the va_start or va_copy macro, or if the va_end macro is not invoked before the return, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: This actually answers the questions.

Answer (score 2):

No, the other alternative is `va_copy()`. They both needed to be paired with `va_end()`.

In other cases there is no point in doing so.

Comment: In other cases, the behaviour is undefined (by omission).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your answer correctly. Do you mean to intend that `va_end` should be preceded by `va_copy` or is it that there is not such restriction and `va_end` can be called stand alone.

Comment: That means `va_start()` needs a `va_end()` and `va_copy()` needs a `va_end()`. In other cases, you don't need it. Using it nevertheleass is a) senseless and b) probably invokes UB (undefined behaviour). That means anything can happen between nothing (it doesn't matter), data corruption to abnormal program termination.

Comment: @glglgl: You forgot "pink elephants" and "premature heat-death of the universe" as results of UB.